# Can we have a search function on our own answers

Tags: feature-request

Can we have a search function on our answers/questions to filter them out. I know that I answered a question before, now I need to search within roughly 350 answers to find the post I want.

Comment: There already.  Search from [user page](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4364303/mouser) (note the user:364303 in the search bar).  For example, searching your posts for 'string': http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A4364303+string

Comment: As MichaelT points out, a `user:me` added to your search will only search your posts.

Comment: For more fun, click on the 'advanced search tips' on the side when doing a [search](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=foo).  Things like favorites is also nice at times.